# How to make ListView change ItemControl to VirtualizingStackPanel at runtime

Tags: wpf, listview, virtualization, itemspanel

OK, so, I have a ListView-derived control that changes Grouping and ItemsSource on the fly.  When I group such that the scrollbars dissapear, and then change my ItemsSource to a different ICollectionView, my scrollbars do not return.

The basic problem is that ListView changes to a VirtualizedStackPanel when grouping is activated and does not change back when grouping is de-activated.

I don't mind that virtualization is disabled when grouping--this is not a problem. What I need is a way to make the ListView regenerate it's ItemPanel when I change the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add an event handler to the [SourceUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated.aspx) event and then reset the [ItemsPanelTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate.aspx) to a template defined in your [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742538.aspx)?

Something like:

```
public MyWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MyListView.SourceUpdated += new EventHandler<DataTransferEventArgs>( OnSourceUpdated );
}

void OnSourceUpdated( object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e )
{
   MyListView.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)Resources["MyItemsPanelTemplate"];
}
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks! Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes on the problem.